# $f(x)$ is a polynomial which satisfies $f(x)f(1/x)+5-3f(x)-3f(1/x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$. If $f(2)=11$, find $f(3)$.

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> $f(x)$ is a polynomial which satisfies $f(x)f(\frac 1 x)+5-3f(x)-3f(\frac 1 x)=0$ for all $x\in \mathbb R-\{0\}$. If $f(2)=11$, find f(3).

I simplified the functional equation down to $g(x)g(\frac 1 x)=4$, where $g(x)=f(x)-3$. I was able to get correct answer by assuming $f(x)$ to be a quadratic polynomial and putting values of $f(2)$ and $f(1/2)$, but I would appreciate a proper solution of this functional equation, specifically in solving $g(x)g(\frac 1x)=4$.

Comment: Please use LaTeX/MathJax to write your question. It makes it much easier on the readers.

Comment: Hint: Show that if $g(x) \neq Ax^k$, then $g(x) g(1/x)$ will have non-constant terms. 

Then, based on the values of $g(2), g(1/2)$, figure out what $A, k$ are.